# Overwrite a specific implementation of an interface to be injected as part of a collection

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Say I have the following IWindsorInstaller implementations:

```
public interface IComponent {}

public class Component1 : IComponent {}

public class Component2 : IComponent {}

public class Component3 : IComponent {}

public interface IComponentManager {}

public class ComponentManager : IComponentManager
{
    public ComponentManager(IEnumerable<IComponent> components)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ComponentInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IComponent>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<Component1>()));
        container.Register(Component.For<IComponent>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<Component2>()));
        container.Register(Component.For<IComponent>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<Component3>()));
        container.Register(Component.For<IComponentManager>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<ComponentManager>()));
    }
}

public class Component2Stub : IComponent{}

public class DebugInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IComponent>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<Component2Stub>()));
        // Here I want to remove the original Component2 registration
        // or override the registration for IComponentManager to use the
        // above in place of Component2
    }
}
```

These classes are instantiated in Windsor by listing in the app.config.

Is there a way to do what I want shown in the comments above?

Answer (score 0):

You could register the subdependency resolver below in debug mode before the CollectionResolver:

public class DebugDependencyResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
    {
        IKernel _kernel;

```
    public DebugDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        if (model.Implementation != typeof(ComponentManager)) return false;
        if (dependency.TargetType != typeof (IEnumerable<IComponent>)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var handlers = _kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(IComponent));
        var components = new List<IComponent>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            if (handler.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(Component2)) continue;
            components.Add((IComponent)handler.Resolve(context));
        }
        return components;
    }
}
```

Good luck,
Marwijn.

Comment: I ended up just naming all of the components, then calling them out using the `ServiceOverrides()` method.  Given that it's obsolete, I'll have to try this out.  Thanks.